# Inserting with date increment using while loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have  3 columns in a table `Index_tbl` `date`,`brand` and `Index`.And the date starts from 26/1/2012 for Brand A and 18/2/2013 for Brand B.Now I have to insert rows into this table for all the dates before the start date from 1/1/2012 for 'A' brand with Index as '0'.How can I do this in one shot.There are 27 brands and writing a single `insert` for each date is cumbersome.

```
 Declare @min_date 
    set @min_date=select min(dt) from temp_tm_data_final_4 where brand='A'

            while (min_date > 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000)
                BEGIN
                Insert into temp_tm_data_final_4 
                (date,brand,Index)
                values
                (dateadd(day,-1,@min_date),'A',0)
                END
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will fulfill your requirement:

```
Declare @min_date 
        set @min_date=select min(dt) from temp_tm_data_final_4 where brand='A'


;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,@min_date) Dates

    UNION  ALL 

    SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,Dates)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(day,-1,Dates) > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
)
INSERT into temp_tm_data_final_4 (date,brand,Index)
SELECT Dates,'A',0
FROM CTE
```